# Debian 10 - Run android emulator with AVD Manager

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator, kvm, avd-manager

My dockerfile is here:

```
FROM openjdk:8

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget unzip && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV ANDROID_HOME  /android-sdk-linux
ENV PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools/bin:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools

RUN wget -q https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip -O android-sdk-tools.zip \
    && unzip -q android-sdk-tools.zip -d ${ANDROID_HOME} \
    && rm android-sdk-tools.zip

RUN yes | sdkmanager --licenses
RUN touch /root/.android/repositories.cfg
RUN sdkmanager "tools" "platform-tools" 

# 0 (Stable), 1 (Beta), 2 (Dev), and 3 (Canary)
RUN yes | sdkmanager --update --channel=3

RUN sdkmanager \
    "system-images;android-29;google_apis;x86" \
    "system-images;android-28;google_apis;x86" \
    "system-images;android-26;google_apis;x86" \
    "system-images;android-25;google_apis;armeabi-v7a" \
    "system-images;android-24;default;armeabi-v7a" \
    "system-images;android-22;default;armeabi-v7a" \
    "system-images;android-19;default;armeabi-v7a" \
    "extras;android;m2repository" \
    "extras;google;m2repository" \
    "extras;google;google_play_services" \
    "extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout;1.0.2" \
    "extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout;1.0.1" \
    "add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-23" \
    "add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-22" \
    "add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-21"
```

OS version: `PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"`. To create an android emulator, I run below commands.

```
$sdkmanager "emulator"
$echo "yes" | sdkmanager --licenses
$sdkmanager "--verbose" "--channel=0" "emulator"

$emulator -list-avds
$sdkmanager --install "system-images;android-29;default;x86"
$echo "no" | avdmanager --verbose create avd --force --name "my_local_emulator" --package "system-images;android-29;default;x86" --tag "default" --abi "x86"
$emulator -list-avds
my_local_emulator
```

Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${ANDROID_HOME}/tools/lib64:${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator/lib64:${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator/lib64/qt/lib
```

I get an error when I start the emulator

```
$ANDROID_HOME/emulator/emulator @my_local_emulator "-no-audio" "-no-window" "-no-boot-anim" "-netdelay" "none" "-no-snapshot" "-wipe-data" "-gpu" "swiftshader_indirect" "-camera-back" "none" "-camera-front" "none" &
```

> emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware
>   acceleration! Please ensure KVM is properly installed and usable. CPU
>   acceleration status: /dev/kvm is not found: VT disabled in BIOS or KVM
>   kernel module not loaded More info on configuring VM acceleration on
>   Linux:
>   https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-linux
>   General information on acceleration:
>   https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.

To solve this error, I run below command:
`echo "yes" | apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin ubuntu-vm-builder bridge-utils ia32-libs-multiarch`

> Reading package lists... Building dependency tree... Reading state
>   information... Package libvirt-bin is not available, but is referred
>   to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has
>   been obsoleted, or is only available from another source E: Package
>   'libvirt-bin' has no installation candidate E: Unable to locate
>   package ubuntu-vm-builder E: Unable to locate package
>   ia32-libs-multiarch

I have tried many commands and possible solutions, but none of them doesn't work for me.
How can I run the emulator without android studio on debian 10?

Answer (score 0):

Try the `-no-accel` flag when you start the emulator, maybe this will help.

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline

> Disable emulator VM acceleration when using an x86 or x86_64 system image. It's useful for debugging only and is the same as specifying -accel off.